# Delphi IDE some panels are missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 11 and many time when I click the "Run without debugging" button, my program starts to execute. When I close my program, some Delphi IDE panels are missing. It looks like this:

[image]

This is my Delphi IDE version.

[image]

Is this a bug or a configuration? I can't find an option that controls this behavior. I can't make the missing panels show up again, and I have to restart the IDE.

Comment: There's a known bug that makes panels go blank. It could be this one you are affected by. Have you tried to reapply the "Default Layout" configuration using the title bar controls?

Comment: This is a bug in Alexandria https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35481

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes I tried, but to no avail.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thanks for the link! I don't know how other people can live with this bug. It almost happens every time to me. Think about it, whenever I run the program, I have to restart the IDE...

Comment: Not all people are equally affected. I have seen if few times, but most of the time IDE works fine for me. I know some people that have it every single time when they run debugger. It appears to be some timing issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Delphi 11. Fix for this issue will be released with 11.1 update.

Quality Portal Report [RSP-35481](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35481)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the exact same version and had the same issue. I tried changing the configuration, but it didn't work.
Eventually, I found this works for me -- right-click the Delphi exe, choose "Run as Administrator."
If the panels are still missing, try: run as administrator - open project - compile all - build all - debug.
Also, don't forget to set the project's Build Configurations to debug instead of release.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this with a very fresh install of D11.3 Pro on Win10
Running Delphi as administrator and Randomly the IDE windows go blank after closing an app from debug mode - no amount of fiddling with the layouts or windows fixes anything other than a restart...